# Unary operator ! cannot be applied to type struct

Tags: solidity

I have a struct, and a mapping, like

```
struct Foo {
   string bar;
}
mapping(string => Foo) private valueToFoo;
```

I want to make sure that this value Foo for value `baz` does not exist before proceeding:

```
Foo memory foo = valueToFoo[_value];
require(!foo; "Such foo already exists");
```

Can I convert struct to bool?

Comment: you need to compare the string „bar“ if it is empty

Comment: @MajdTL but if `valueToFoo[_value]` is not defined, will I be able to access `bar`?

Comment: Yes it is accessible and you don’t get undefined error like JavaScript